# nested resources or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

User has many Classifieds. A classified is only renewed, modified, shown/hidden by their own owners. There is an index and show pages of all classifieds that are public. Is there any advantage to using nested resources or should I just manage the process through permissions/current_user?

Answer (score 0):

There is an advantage to using nested resources with polymorphic associations if you are thinking in terms of ease of filtering. You could have `/classifieds` or `/user/1/classifieds` for accessing all or filtering by user. It would also make the associations simpler to manage. For example you would not need to pass a user_id to a classified update form accessed at `/user/1/classifieds/1/edit`. I found the resources don't take very long to set up and provide some nice benefits. You could even check out this gem that seems popular that seems to make the whole process easier: [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources).